# Why am I having an issue with making a nullable integer a property?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, properties, nullable

I made a modification to an existing piece of .NET 4 code to make a new property which consisted of a nullable integer. It runs in a Windows Service.

```
    public static int? Port
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

The concept was that if the value was null it was ignored but if it wasn't then it was used (a non-default scenario)

```
    if (Port != null)
    {
        client = new Client( Server, Port.Value );
    }
    else
    {
        client = new Client( Server );
    }
```

On my machine, it works as expected.

However, when deployed to our testing servers I'm getting exceptions when it's called from an ASP.NET site. Here's the formatted exception output:

```
Exception: System.MissingMethodException
Exception Message: Method not found: 'Void NameOfAssembly.set_Port(System.Nullable`1<Int32>)'.
Exception Data: System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
Exception TargetSite: ** Unable to GetValue **
Exception HelpLink: NULL
```

It's as if either the code wasn't deployed correctly, or it just can't find the automatic get/set methods. A coworker has made a subsequent change that does work in our testing environment so I don't think it's a deployment issue.

I can't think of any reason this would happen, other than possibly Windows Server (2008 R2) operating differently than Windows 7 where I developed it, but that's a stretch.

Has anyone ever seen this before?

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like the ASP.NET site somehow uses an outdated version of your assembly. If this error occurs in compiled code (rather than in an .aspx page), you have possibly compiled it against an updated version of the assembly, but deployed it without including the updated assembly.

Comment: I probably didn't phrase it well but the code in question is in a Windows Service that's called from an ASP.NET page. And since a subsequent change to the code from someone else works fine I don't *think* it's an issue of an outdated assembly but I'm not ruling it out.

Comment: How does the ASP.NET page call the service? Does the error occur in the service or in the page?

Comment: @Aasmund: in the service, but the exception bubbles up to the ASP.NET page and is logged there.

Comment: @schnapple yes,but what is the method your using to get a reference to the assembly that is the service? If you're using Reflection, check the gac on the server, there may well be an out of date assembly in it that is what your assembly is hooking to.

Comment: @John Yeah we looked into that, it's not in the GAC (although an earlier version was) but the problem remains even after we removed everything from the GAC. I might still be missing something but I can't figure out what else to try.

Comment: @schnapple Again assuming you're using .NET reflection, try logging the Location property of the Assembly reference. That should tell you where .NET is getting the assembly from.

Answer (score 1):

I would open the Assembly in Reflector and *really* make sure the method is there.

Answer (score 0):

As @Aasmund mentions it's probably an out of date assembly.  You mention that it's in a Windows Service, did you try restarting the service after deploying?

Comment: Yes, the service is stopped, deployed, then restarted. And a subsequent change works, so I *think* the code has been deployed but it's not beyond the realm of possibility that something's been cross wired.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use if(Port.HasValue) instead of if(Port !=null)

Comment: But I don't think that's the real issue here.

Comment: True; this is more a matter of style. Using `Port != null` is perfectly legal.

Comment: -1. While there's nothing wrong with this style (or comparing to null; they both compile to the same code), this does not address the question at all.

Comment: For future reference, this sort of response would be better as a comment to the original question.